# Keep child object inside parent in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `Collider2D` to make a border in my 2D game. I have another `Gameobject` inside this border and user can move it up/down by using a virtual Joystick .

Now i want keep **all of childs inside this border** and when user move them `up/down` they dont go beind my special Border that is  a `Collider2D`.

I have tried to do this before by using 2 `gameobject` on the top and down of my border for getting the position of them and check each the child objects but if i have more objects it's not a good idea.

What i want to do is like bellow picture

[image]

How i can do this ?

Comment: I'd advise you making your question clearer : for now it's quite difficult to understand what you're aiming for. Consider adding the code you already produced as well as screenshots or graphic representation of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Kardux i think the problem is very clear and this problem happened before coding then i have't any code right now . this problem is in mind before doing anything how you ask screenshot or code when there is no anything :)

Comment: Well since you said _"I have tried to do this before [...] it's not a good idea"_ I guess it was legit for me to guess you already produced something before asking for help ? Also providing a quick drawing of what you have in mind isn't that much time consuming ([here](http://imgur.com/a/vjG63) is an example of what you could have done (don't know if I understood your question correctly)). Anyway my bad if I didn't sound helpful : I only gave you this comment since it was my own point of view when reading your question. Finally I guess provided answers should be enough to solve your problem ;)

Comment: @Kardux Thanks . i will use your advice in future and i used your drawing in my question .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you (in your code) always check if your GameObject is inside of your bounds. From there, simply stop modifying the position, when it is out of the bounds.

```
PolygonCollider2D poly = transform.parent.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();
// Check if the position is inside of the bounds
if (poly.bounds.Contains(transform.position))
{
    // GameObject is inside of the bounds
}
else 
{
    // GameObject is outside of the bounds!
}
```

A quick example of how you would do it:

```
Vector2 movement;
// Calculate movement here
Vector2 newPosition = transform.position + movement;
PolygonCollider2D poly = transform.parent.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();
if (poly.bounds.Contains(newPosition))
{
    transform.position = newPosition;
}
else 
{
    // ignore
}
```

**Edit:**

Because we are trying to get `Bounds.Contain` of `2DCollider`  we must check the `Vector2` position of `GameObjects`

Comment: this not work in my game i tested it by 2 gameObject and make one of them child of another and i gave these objects collider and write above codes for them but always else worked for me . this answer is not true

Comment: It is true, but the parent has to have the collider.

Comment: the problem is about getting new position . when i test it by using Vector2 for finding new position of gameobject it worked

Comment: this link helped me to find the problem look at :
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/930309/collider2dboundscontains-not-working-properly.html

Answer (score 2):

You can have 4 Edge Colliders instead of one 2D Collider as the border.

This way you can restrict your GameObject's movements if your GameObject has a 2D Rigidbody and a 2D Collider attached.

### Note

Colliders do not collide from the inside.